# How to pass arguments for intermediate destinations, that are recreated for a back stack when launching a deep link with navigation component?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Deep link via navigation component works perfectly fine, when there is only one destination in a back stack and it does not need any data to be created.

However it is very common situation, like below
[image]
and it is not clear to me how to pass neccessary arguments for Destination B and Destination A, while recreating them in the back stack.

While creating `PendingIntent` we set destination C and pass arguments C for that destination specifically. But I can't see any way to pass data to Destinations B and A, even though I do have that data at the moment of the deep link creation.

I am aware that in order for a destination to be created in a back stack it should be a start destination, so I imply, that Destination B is a start destination of a nested graph and Destination A is a start destination in main graph.

Also, I am aware, that this problem could be solved using shared ViewModel etc, but I hope that I still miss something and it can be solved by the component's API itself.

Comment: I have a similar question. In my case, I have deep links set to:
B: /path/{id}
C: /path{id}/{id2}
And I thought I could retrieve "id" from getArguments in B

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple. All arguments are already there.

Simply calling `getArguments()` from any fragment interrested does the trick.

I suppose that it is because arguments are stored at the activity intent level and since fragments all share same activity, they can access them independently.

Answer (score 0):

Share data between a group of related destinations: [ViewModel and Jetpack Navigation : NavGraph with a ViewModel](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-with-saved-state-jetpack-navigation-data-binding-and-coroutines-df476b78144e#d2bd)